# Android WebView not respecting scaling percentage

Tags: android, webview

I have a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) which I'm trying to have scale to a certain percent on loading the page. The iPhone version of this software uses the HTML meta-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=0.95, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=1">
```

Since Android's WebView doesn't seem to respect that tag I hard-coded the percent using [setInitialScale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale%28int%29). However, the WebView is just flat-out ignoring this method call. No matter what number I put in there it shows at 100%.

Ideas?

**Update:** It's not working in the emulator, on my Droid (Motorola), or on my G1 (HTC).

Comment: hi what android device are u using?

Comment: Emulator, G1, Droid... not working on any of them.

Answer (score 5):

Some HTC devices have problems with `WebView`, try this snippet!

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

myWebView = new WebView(this);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.setInitialScale(100);      
try {
   Method m = myWebView.getClass().getMethod("setIsCacheDrawBitmap", boolean.class);
    if (m != null) {
        m.invoke(myWebView, false);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    }
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
}

myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: I found it this is the original link http://community.htc.com/na/htc-forums/android/f/91/p/2332/8538.aspx =)

Answer (score 1):

did you enable the zoom support for your webview?

```
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below helped me when mine wasn't responding. Worth a shot:

```
mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
mywebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true) ; 
mywebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true) ; 
mywebview.setInitialScale(1) ; 
mywebview.loadUrl(sURL);
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my Android 2.3.6 phone. Setting `initial-scale` for the viewport still has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you running?  [It seems that 2.0 and below had an issue with this but was resolved in the 2.1.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5143)

Comment: The link seems to be broken. I know it's been a long time, but if you remember the issue, can you provide the new link?

Answer (score 0):

Can see several options.

1 . Probably there's something wrong with your code. Here's the most simple code and I can tell it works for me. Content is scaled.

```
WebView webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
webview1.setInitialScale(30);
webview1.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

So please post your code. All code related to WebView configuration.
I test on emulator 2.2

2 . Probably there's something wrong with url you test. You can test "http://stackoverflow.com" as I test with it and it is scaled fine.

3 . Maybe we use different SDKs. What SDK do you build against? I mean what is your target in default.properties? What is your uses-sdk in AndroidManifest.xml?

Here's a simple test that works fine for me http://open-pim.com/tmp/WebViewTest.zip. You may try it too.

Comment: This worked! But not in my apps. Turns out the meta viewport tags: initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; were preventing setInitialScale() from working. After removing them it works.

Comment: This example does not work with WebView on Android 2.3.6. The Stackoverflow website is not scaled.

Answer (score 0):

The `meta` tag works for me, if I separate the parameters with semicolons (;) instead of commas (,). I've used this in the past:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

And it works, at least in the browser. I'm not sure about a `WebView`, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: the ';' did nothing for me.

Comment: That's invalid content, only commas are allowed: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/