# setInitialScale for older devices?

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I'm currently working on a webView application,
but I just can't get the initial zoom to work out, which should be at 150% when starting the app.

```
private static final int zoom = 150;
webView.setInitialScale(zoom);
```

This seems to be working fine on newer devices, but is there an alternative to older devices as well?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got to solve it. If anybody runs into the same issue at some point in time:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
```

```
webView = new WebView(this);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(65);
        try {
            Method m = webView.getClass().getMethod("setIsCacheDrawBitmap", boolean.class);
            if (m != null) {
                m.invoke(webView, false);
                webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        }

        webView.loadUrl("https://duckduckgo.com/");
```

Found the solution in here:
[Android WebView not respecting scaling percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3025657/)